# How to load next set of elements once button is clicked

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a multiple choice app. I have a `List` of objects which have all the necessary information (question, four answers and a correct one). Four buttons have the four answers assigned to them as text.

When the user clicks a button the app checks if the selected answer is correct or false. And I need to load the next set of information to the respective components.

Tried calling `loadQuestionElements` inside the `onClick` method but it didn't produce the requested result.

**MainActivity**

```
FetchQ fetchq = new FetchQ();
List<Question> questions = null;
String correctAnswer;
private Bundle savedInstanceState;
int iterator = 0;
Question question;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView tQuestion = findViewById(R.id.textViewQuestion);
    Button answer1 = findViewById(R.id.bAnswer1);
    Button answer2 = findViewById(R.id.bAnswer2);
    Button answer3 = findViewById(R.id.bAnswer3);
    Button answer4 = findViewById(R.id.bAnswer4);

    answer1.setOnClickListener(this);
    answer2.setOnClickListener(this);
    answer3.setOnClickListener(this);
    answer4.setOnClickListener(this);



    //Retrieves all the questions from the database
    try {
        questions = fetchq.execute().get();
        Collections.shuffle(questions);
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.question = loadQuestionElements(questions, iterator, tQuestion, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4);
    this.correctAnswer = question.getCorrectAnswer();

}
```

This is how I load the information to the respective components

```
public Question loadQuestionElements(List<Question> questions, int iterator, TextView question, Button option1, Button option2, Button option3, Button option4){
    Question q = questions.get(iterator);
    question.setText(q.getQuestion());
    option1.setText(q.getOption1());
    option2.setText(q.getOption2());
    option3.setText(q.getOption3());
    option4.setText(q.getOption4());
    this.correctAnswer = q.getCorrectAnswer();
    this.iterator++;
    return q;
}
```

Don't know if it helps but here is my onClick method

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button button = (Button) v;

    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bAnswer1:
            if (this.question.isCorrect(button.getText().toString(),this.correctAnswer)){
                button.setBackgroundColor(0xFF4CAF50);//Set button background color to green
            }else{
                button.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF44336);//Set button background color to red
            }
        case R.id.bAnswer2:
            if (this.question.isCorrect(button.getText().toString(),this.correctAnswer)){
                button.setBackgroundColor(0xFF4CAF50);//Set button background color to green
            }else{
                button.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF44336);//Set button background color to red
            }
        case R.id.bAnswer3:
            if (this.question.isCorrect(button.getText().toString(),this.correctAnswer)){
                button.setBackgroundColor(0xFF4CAF50);//Set button background color to green
            }else{
                button.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF44336);//Set button background color to red
            }
        case R.id.bAnswer4:
            if (this.question.isCorrect(button.getText().toString(),this.correctAnswer)){
                button.setBackgroundColor(0xFF4CAF50);//Set button background color to green
            }else{
                button.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF44336);//Set button background color to red
            }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new Method and call this method after every switch case statement

```
private void getNewQuestion(){
    this.question = loadQuestionElements(questions, iterator, tQuestion, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4);
    this.correctAnswer = question.getCorrectAnswer();
    }
```

Now for switch case, after each case, you have to load new question

```
switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bAnswer1:
            if (this.question.isCorrect(button.getText().toString(),this.correctAnswer)){
                button.setBackgroundColor(0xFF4CAF50);//Set button background color to green
            }else{
                button.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF44336);//Set button background color to red
            }
             getNewQuestion();
             break;
        case R.id.bAnswer2:
            if (this.question.isCorrect(button.getText().toString(),this.correctAnswer)){
                button.setBackgroundColor(0xFF4CAF50);//Set button background color to green
            }else{
                button.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF44336);//Set button background color to red
            }
            getNewQuestion();
            break;
        case R.id.bAnswer3:
            if (this.question.isCorrect(button.getText().toString(),this.correctAnswer)){
                button.setBackgroundColor(0xFF4CAF50);//Set button background color to green
            }else{
                button.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF44336);//Set button background color to red
            }
            getNewQuestion();
            break;
        case R.id.bAnswer4:
            if (this.question.isCorrect(button.getText().toString(),this.correctAnswer)){
                button.setBackgroundColor(0xFF4CAF50);//Set button background color to green
            }else{
                button.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF44336);//Set button background color to red
            }
            getNewQuestion();
            break;
   }
```

Comment: Also make sure to check the list size before getting new question from the questions list. Question q = questions.get(iterator);
otherwise index out of bound exception may occur

Comment: It seems that it's not that easy, or I am missing something. If I implement the ```getNewQuestion``` I will not be able to access the UI components that are inside the ```onCreate``` method.

Comment: Declare them globally
private TextView tQuestion;
private  Button answer1, answer2 , answer3, answer4 ;

Comment: Is your problem still there?